# Writing an API wrapper gem - what's the best way to persist API Token per instance?

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, token

I'm writing an REST API Wrapper ruby gem, here's how I want it to work:

```
    # to start, initialize a client
    client = APIWrapper.new "someToken"
    # then you can fetch a collection of resources
    client.some_resources.fetch
    # you don't have to always start with `client` when you have a resource loaded
    resource = client.some_resource.first
    resource.do_stuff
    moar_resource = resource.some_nested_resources.find({foo: 'bar'})
    moar_resource.do_other_stuff
    # and you can run multiple clients with different tokens
    client_1 = APIWrapper.new "token 1"
    client_2 = APIWrapper.new "token 2"
```

so the service (which is out of my control) requires an "apiToken" to be passed as a parameter in every request. So I need to pass the token in `Client` to each nested resources so they can work without relying on information stored in `client` object. (some api wrappers will always require you to start your action from `client`, eg. `client.resources["someId"].do_stuff`

What I'm doing right now is that I have a `connection` object, which is a `Faraday` instance, with apiToken set as a default parameter, in `Client` once it is initialized. Then every time I'm initializing a resource instance (eg. `resource = client.resources.first` ) I pass down the `connection` object, so it can use the existing connection to perform API calls.

After writing 5,6 classes I started thinking if there is a better way to do this since in every class I'm doing something like

```
    Module APIWrapper
        class Resource(options = {})
            @conn = options[:connection]
            @attribute_1 = options[:attribute_1]
            # ... assign other attributes
        end
    end
```

I've looked at some other API Wrapper's repos but I haven't found an answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of Object Oriented programming.

There are hacky ways to do this in ruby, such as saving state on a module as such:

```
module Client
  class << self
    attr_accessor :connection
  end
end

Client.connection = # Your faraday object, with API token

class Resource
  def some_call
    Client.connection.post #whatever
  end
end
```

This is generally considered pretty ugly.

If I were you I would simply create a Resource superclass that takes the @conn in the constructor. In every instance, call the superclass's constructor.

You will still have to pass in the @conn object when you initialize a resource, but the assignment will be all in one place and DRY.

Comment: hmm. thanks. but in your example, i don't think it's still possible to have multiple `client`s with different api tokens, correct?

Comment: No, not really. If you are going to have multiple clients with different API tokens, you should definitely just use a superclass :)